# Meteor: Facebook username not displaying

Tags: facebook, meteor

I have a Facebook login running within my app and a user page to display the most important user details. When I login using a password then the following code:

```
user: function(){
    return Meteor.user().username
},
```

with:

```
<h1>Welcome {{user}}</h1>
```

return the username. When i am logged in with Facebook login the username is blank.

**How can I access the current users username when logged in through Facebook?**

Thanks

Comment: If you run `console.log(Meteor.user())` in your browser console while logged in with Facebook, you should be able to find something useful in `services.facebook` or `profile`.

Comment: Check out how the user document looks in database. I recommend a GUI tool like [mongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) for that. You'll see a subdocument filled with user profile from Facebook, including user name. It's pretty easy task - sadly I don't have an app with Facebook login handy to give you the precise answer, but finding it out for yourself is a handy ability.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the comment by @user3374348 managed to find it

Facebook username is found in profile.name. So

```
 return Meteor.user().username || Meteor.user().profile.name
```

returns either the username if available or otherwise the Facebook name.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
return Meteor.user().username || Meteor.user().profile.name
```

It works for me.